# Rails: assert_select gives nokogiri error when testing for attribute with numeric value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, nokogiri

In my rails integration test, I'm trying to test for the presence of a checkbox with a given value (which is the ID of an object, an integer).

This line: `assert_select "input[type=checkbox][value=#{c.id.to_s}]"` generates the following error:

> Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '283557850' after 'equal'
>
> (283557850 is the ID of the object).

What's confusing is that I only get this error when testing for numerical values. If I put in some letters, like `assert_select "input[type=checkbox][value=test#{c.id.to_s}]"`, I no longer get that error (obviously the test fails since the value of my checkbox is not actually "test283557850").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `input[type=checkbox][value=123]` is not a valid CSS selector. When querying on attributes the value must start with a letter or be quoted.

```
assert_select "input[type=checkbox][value='#{c.id.to_s}']"
```

You can problem solve these kind of issues by using the browser console and [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I had to use " instead of ' to get it to work (and escape them), so: `assert_select "input[type=checkbox][value=\"#{c.id}\"]"`

Answer (score 0):

Attached is my `assert_xpath`. It's better than `assert_select` because XPath treats XML as a database where it can make arbitrarily complex queries.

Your query would be `assert_xpath "//input[@type='checkbox' and @value='#{c.id.to_s}']"`, or better yet `assert_xpath '//input[@type="checkbox" and @value=$value]', value: c.id.to_s`.

`assert_xpath` can also nest. For example:

```
assert_xpath '//label[ contains(text(), "Group:") ]' do
  assert_xpath 'select[ "group_id" = @name ]' do
    assert_xpath 'option[ "Anonymous users" = text() and "13" = @value ]'
    assert_xpath 'option[ "B Team" = text() and "11" = @value and "selected" = @selected ]'
  end
end
```

Paste this into your `test_helper.rb` file:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def assert_xml(xml)
    @xdoc = Nokogiri::XML(xml, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)
    refute_nil @xdoc
    return @xdoc
  end

  def assert_html(html=nil)
    html ||= @response.body
    @xdoc = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)
    refute_nil @xdoc
    return @xdoc
  end

  def assert_xpath(path, replacements={}, &block)
    @xdoc ||= nil  #  Avoid a dumb warning
    @xdoc or assert_html  #  Because assert_html snags @response.body for us
    element = @xdoc.at_xpath(path, nil, replacements)

    unless element
      complaint = "Element expected in:\n`#{@xdoc}`\nat:\n`#{path}`"
      replacements.any? and complaint += "\nwith: " + replacements.pretty_inspect
      raise Minitest::Assertion, complaint
    end

    if block
      begin
        waz_xdoc = @xdoc
        @xdoc = element
        block.call(element)
      ensure
        @xdoc = waz_xdoc
      end
    end

    return element
  end

  def refute_xpath(path, replacements={}, &block)
    @xdoc ||= nil  #  Avoid a dumb warning
    @xdoc or assert_html  #  Because assert_html snags @response.body for us
    element = @xdoc.at_xpath(path, nil, replacements)

    if element
      complaint = "Element not expected in:\n`#{@xdoc}`\nat:\n`#{path}`"
      replacements.any? and complaint += "\nwith: " + replacements.pretty_inspect
      raise Minitest::Assertion, complaint
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This code would be a lot better if you wrote it as a module that could be included instead of copy-pasting it in into `ActiveSupport::TestCase`.